# How to find deployed transaction hash of any given contract in chain, with just "contract address" information?

Tags: contract-deployment

Am trying to write small application which will be able to find Contract deployment transaction with only input parameter - contract address. The application should be able to search entire net.,i,e say Rinkeby and should exactly find deployed transaction hash. This is applicable for any given contract address in rinkeby. I do not want to search with events or logs. Specifically am looking for how to find all the transactions with "0x0" as target programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself- Its pretty simple infact:

1. Search for all the transaction from 0 to LatestBlock
2. Get transactions in each block and loop through transactions one by one.
3. Get Transaction receipt in each transaction and check whether its deployment transaction ['to' = '0x0'] and if so, get contract address.
4. If given contract address matched input address, hurray we found the deployed transaction.

Comment: This will not work for contracts that were deployed by another contract.

Comment: can you please explain in detail?I think "to" = 0x0 in the deployment txn, irrespective of whether external account or contract initiated the txn

Comment: A contract A can deploy a 'child' contract B with `B child = new B(params);` (in solidity). The child contract was created by an 'internal' transaction and it has no corresponding normal transaction with null 'to'.